# Software updates crashes on nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, update-manager

I just downloaded and installed 14.04 to replace a xubuntu 14.10 that has been crashing on every reboot. Now, with nothing else installed, Software updates crashes when it gets to the nvidia driver.  Any hints on where to start to fix this would be appreciated.

```
mobo: M4A89GTD-PRO 
Bios: 2101 
cpu: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor 
ram: 6111188 kB 
hdd: ATA OCZ-VERTEX3 
gpu: GeForce GT 440 Mouse / keyboard: M510, K350 single unifying receiver 
Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (x86_64) Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

edit - based on a recommendation below, I've completely wiped the proprietary driver and replaced it with the xorg.edgers driver. Technically, it corrected the problem, so this is solved.

Comment: You seem to be having a problematic Ubuntu install. (to say the least)  My answer to your [other](http://askubuntu.com/questions/566746/800-x-600-cannot-select-higher-resolution) NVidia question will solve this problem too.

Comment: I appreciate your assist on this, but it certainly raises 2 questions in my mind almost immediately: 1. If the standard driver is so poor, then why isn't this other driver packaged by default? But more importantly, 2. Why is the proprietary driver even available as an option if it crashes the updater? Xubuntu 14.10 was using the nvidia 331.104 driver for several months with no issue - will Ubuntu catch up and be able to incorporate the proprietary driver eventually? Sorry - still confused. Ubuntu used to be able to use the proprietary driver.