# 800 X 600 cannot select higher resolution

Tags: nvidia, resolution

Well, this is new.

In the middle of troubleshooting all of the other issues with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, I rebooted and it now comes up with a resolution of 800 X 600, and there are no other resolutions available.

I've already re-installed the nvidia-current driver twice.

```
mobo: M4A89GTD-PRO 
Bios: 2101 
cpu:  AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor 
ram:  6111188 kB 
hdd:  ATA OCZ-VERTEX3 
gpu:  GeForce GT 440 
Mouse / keyboard: M510, K350 single unifying receiver 
Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (x86_64) Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

edit - I should point out, this is a brand new installation from a fresh download.  I have not changed or altered or installed anything at all beyond running software updater a few times, installing the latest nvidia-current driver, and doing a sudo-apt update a few times.  But everything is exactly as it was installed with all of the defaults.

edit - based on a recommendation below, I've completely wiped the proprietary driver and replaced it with the xorg.edgers driver.  Technically, it corrected the problem, so this is solved.

Comment: Go to the dash, type  "additional" and click on additional drivers.  What do you see?

Comment: @Fabby, not at all a duplicate of that...

Comment: @psusi: Oops, sorry, forgot to delete!  :(  (done now)

Comment: @snurfle: could you delete your comments (deleted mine already) to keep your *excellent* question uncluttered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've added the xorg-edgers PPA, you have a lot of drivers to choose from:

```
apt-cache search nvidia-3 | sort
```

Currently I'm running the `nvidia-settings --version`

```
nvidia-settings:  version 346.22  (buildd@lgw01-10)  Tue Dec  9 08:42:45 UTC 2014
```

and it seems to be running 10°C cooler (+/- 18°F) then the nvidia-340, so try that one first.

### Steps to follow:

1. Disable the nVIDIA card in the BIOS and reboot (so that any old drivers lingering around can be removed successfully)
2. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346`
3. `sync`
4. `sudo shutdown -h now` (full shut down as soft reboot gave me a problem)
5. Turn on the computer, enable the NVidia card in the BIOS and reboot (For sake of completeness: here I had to do another full shutdown)
6. Check the driver version with `nvidia-settings --version` only!  The "Additional Drivers" doesn't show the correct settings.
7. System settings - Displays should now allow you to take the highest resolution (if not already detected automatically)

That's it!

If your card still gives you a walk down memory lane (Windows 95 behaviour), go to step 2 and try the next (lower) version using the same system

Comment: If it works, don't thank me: press the little grey check-mark below the "0" thus having my reputation and yours go up! ;)